# How to validate pip's --extra-index-url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am unable to find certain packages that should be found from a local package index that I've defined with the `--extra-index-url` in my global `pip.ini` file.

How can I validate that my `pip` is using this properly? In my scenario I'm using a virtual environment.

I have tried `pip config list` because it sounded promising in `pip help`, but I get *nothing* as an output.

Comment: `pip install pkg-to-check== -vvv` will not install anything (because of non-existent `pkg-to-check==` requirement), but print all packages `pip` will attempt to match against the req, along with their URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a module that doesn't exist:

```
pip install --extra-index-url=https://example.com made-up
```

In my case (aside from a lot of errors) I also get:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://example.com
Collecting made-up
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement made-up (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for made-up
```

If you are setup correctly, you should see the extra repo URL in the output. If you are running with defaults the `"Looking in indexes"` line is not shown.